# How to track Solana NFT Collection's transaction history

Tags: transactions, nft, collection

Seems like there's no specific address associated with a Solana NFT Collection.
How does marketplaces like magic eden track transaction history from a collection scale?

For a single NFT, seems like a mixture of getSignaturesForAddress RPC API call and getTransaction RPC API call do the job

Answer (score 3):

The generally recommended solution for this is to index the data from the chain in some sort of operational datastore *off* chain, using a [Geyser plugin](https://docs.solana.com/ar/developing/plugins/geyser-plugins).

Holaplex is one such implementation of an indexer-as-a-service.

Here’s a GraphQL query that you can make to Holaplex to get all NFTs belonging to a collection, by the mint address of the collection.

```
{
  nfts(offset: 0, limit: 50, collection: "t2JCfPQQrAa731ShvnagKAFKfiPrYooy1r7zDTmWVqT") {
    name
    address
    attributes {
      traitType
      value
    }
  }
}
```

Try it out at https://graph.holaplex.com/graphiql

You might like to ask Holaplex to add a query that lets you fetch all purchase events in a GraphQL connection. Looking at https://docs.holaplex.com/ I’m not sure that’s something they currently offer.

Comment: Think a recommended approach for most of these questions nowadays is to use a service like Helius and their webhooks: https://docs.helius.xyz/webhooks/what-are-webhooks